# Segfault in multithreaded OpenGL?

Tags: multithreading, macos, opengl, core-graphics

I'm running into an issue where OpenGL calls in multiple threads sometimes cause a segfault, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm not sharing a context or anything else between threads.

```
invalid CoreGraphics connection
Segmentation fault: 11
```

The actual CGL result code is

```
kCGLBadConnection - Invalid connection to Core Graphics.
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/cgl_opengl/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001186-CH3g-BBCDCEBD

The end use case here is to render images asynchronously with libuv (doing some processing on the CPU then uploading data to the GPU for rendering), but I've worked up a simple test case which replicates this issue.

https://github.com/mikemorris/headless-gl-multithreaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the cause of the crash is multiple threads simultaneously trying to open a display connection in CGLChoosePixelFormat (or XOpenDisplay/glXChooseVisual in GLX). Opening a single connection in the main thread and then using this connection when instantiating new threads (each of which creates their own context) seems to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You need a valid OpenGL context bound to the thread when calling glReadPixels. The CGL variant of `View::resize` unbinds the OpenGL context at the end, so glReadPixels is called without a OpenGL context being active. I think this might be part of the reason of your problem.

Comment: Oops, forgot the the make_active/make_inactive wrapper in the simplified example, updated and still segfaulting. Wondering if I need something akin to XInitThreads?